# How to plot confidence ellipses of a Multiple Correspondence Analysis with binary (dichotomous) predictors?

Tags: r

I've got some trouble when trying to plot 95% confidence elipses in MCA with categorical predictors. Here is a sample from my data and code.

```
CONSTRUCTION<-c("in plaats van", "ten opzichte van", "met behulp van", "ten koste van", "op grond van", "onder leiding van", "in tegenstelling tot", "op basis van")
IDIOSYNC<-c("no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no")
ARTICLE<-c("yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no")
PLURAL<-c("no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no")
MODIF<-c("no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "no")
EXTRAPOS<-c("yes", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no")
COMPLEM<-c("no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "no")
P2OPTION<-c("no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "no")
P1CHBL<-c("no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no")
P2CHBL<-c("no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no")

data.comp.prep<-cbind(CONSTRUCTION, IDIOSYNC, ARTICLE, PLURAL, MODIF, EXTRAPOS, COMPLEM, P2OPTION, P1CHBL, P2CHBL)

ca.comp.prep<-MCA(data.comp.prep[, -c(1, 4, 9)], graph=FALSE)
plot(ca.comp.prep, cex=0.7, col.var="black", col.ind="grey")
ca.comp.prep1<-MCA(data.comp.prep[, -c(4, 9)], quali.sup=1, graph=FALSE)
plot(ca.comp.prep1, invis="ind", col.var="darkgrey", col.quali.sup="black")
```

The problem occurs when I run the code for plotting the ellipses:

```
plotellipses(ca.comp.prep1[, -c(4, 9)], keepvar=1, label="quali")
Error in ca.comp.prep1[, -c(4, 9)] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I don't see where the problem comes from and I'm new in (M)CA.

Answer (score 0):

`ca.comp.prep1` is a list containing the result of the MCA. you are trying to index it like if it was a `data.frame` with two dimensions. The `[,c(4,9)]` is non-sensical here.

Then, you are trying to plot ellipses for the first variable of `ca.comp.prep1`, which is basically a row id (it has a different value for each individual). No ellipse is possible because there is only one point for each category.

My advice is that you should not add the first variable in the MCA; keep studying `ca.comp.prep` and forget about `ca.comp.prep1`. Then to draw ellipses:

```
plotellipses(ca.comp.prep, keepvar=1, label="quali")
```

If you still want that done on `ca.comp.prep1`, try another variable:

```
plotellipses(ca.comp.prep1, keepvar=2, label="quali")
```